# jQuery hover event interrupted by child <input>. Is there a way around this? (chrome issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

**Update: thanks to the comment below, it looks like a chrome specific issue.**

Is there a way around the hover event getting interrupted by mousing over an `<input>` element in jQuery?

Only fade out when going from element to non child element?

Here's a jsfiddle with a live example of the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/2h2Jt/3/

```
$(".hover").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({backgroundColor:'#aaaaaa'}, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 500);
});
```

I'm falling back on CSS, but it would be great to have this animation working :)

#### Update: Fixed in Mac Chrome 11.0.696.65

But still a real issue for those caught between chrome updates.

Comment: That example works fine for me in FF... What browser are you using?

Comment: Oh, you're right! It's on mac chrome 9.0.597.102. Works on my FF / Safari. Snaps! Still, I wonder what a good solution is.

Comment: problem is on windows chrome too fyi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/2h2Jt/140/

```
$(".hover").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa'
    }, 500);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }, 500);
});
```

Seems there is an issue with .hover() and text input in Chrome (try your old code with a button input type)

Comment: JP!, awesome man. Thank you! This has to be a relatively common issue. I use hover() all the time and form inputs are a nice chunk of the web.

Comment: My pleasure :) Yeah, the actual issue may be with mouseenter/mouseleave which .hover(in, out) is shorthand for.

Comment: nice find :D    blah blah char limit

Comment: Still works as of 29/11/2021 and chrome still wigs out if a child element has a hover event that can be triggered by itself or the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this using [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

```
$(this).children().hover(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```